# Add multiple rows per observation

Tags: r, loops, panel

I'm trying to construct a panel dataset that can work as a "vessel" where I can put my real data.

I have information about 346 municipalities, and I want to add daily information, for a total of 166 days. So, for each municipality, I want it to have 166 rows (per day). I've only managed to get a dataset with 57.436 rows (which would be 346*166), but I can't find a way to include both the name of the municipality, and the date. It's one thing or the other. Any ideas on how I can do this? The code that I'm using so far, which produces 346 observations per day, is the following:

```
comunas_panel <- data.frame()
for(i in 1:nrow(codigos_territoriales))  {   
  dates <- data.frame(date = seq(from = as.Date("2019-10-18"), 
                               to = as.Date("2020-03-31"), by = 1))
  comunas_panel = rbind(comunas_panel, dates)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the `expand.grid()` function ([documentation here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/expand.grid)).

It takes any number of arguments that can be named whatever you choose. Each argument is a vector. The result is a data frame with columns named after the arguments, with all possible combinations of the elements from each of the vectors you input. So in this example I use your vector of 166 dates and cross it with a toy example of 3 municipality names to get a data frame with 166*3 = 498 rows and 2 columns (`date` and `municipality`).

```
date <- seq(from = as.Date("2019-10-18"), to = as.Date("2020-03-31"), by = 1)
municipalities <- c('name1', 'name2', 'name3') #etc.

comunas_panel <- expand.grid(municipality = municipalities, date = date)
```

Similar alternatives are `expand_grid()` in tidyverse, and `CJ()` in `data.table`.